# script to get the file last modified date and file name pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a mount point location which is pointing to a blob storage where we have multiple files. We need to find the last modified date for a file along with the file name. I am using the below script
and the list of files are as below:

```
/mnt/schema_id=na/184000-9.jsonl
/mnt/schema_id=na/185000-0.jsonl
/mnt/schema_id=na/185000-22.jsonl
/mnt/schema_id=na/185000-25.jsonl
```

```
import os
import time
# Path to the file/directory
path = "/mnt/schema_id=na"
         
ti_c = os.path.getctime(path)
ti_m = os.path.getmtime(path)
        
c_ti = time.ctime(ti_c)
m_ti = time.ctime(ti_m)
          
print(f"The file located at the path {path} was created at {c_ti} and was last modified at {m_ti}")
```

Comment: You'll obviously need to get the list of files from the path and loop through that list to get the file path and grab the required info.

Comment: Yes please i would need that. Could you please help how to figure out that

Comment: Oh buggered..  I completely missed the "blob storage" point.  My bad!  Thanks to @AxelR!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using operating system-level commands to get file information, then you can't access that exact location - on Databricks it's on the Databricks file system (DBFS).

To get that on the Python level, you need to prepend the `/dbfs` to the path, so it will be:

```py
...
path = "/dbfs/mnt/schema_id=na"
for file_item in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_item)[:5]
    ti_c = os.path.getctime(file_path)
    ...
```

note the `[:5]` - it's used to strip the `/dbfs` prefix from the path to make it compatible with DBFS

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in Databricks, since Databricks runtime 10.4 released on Mar 18, 2022, dbutils.fs.ls() command returns “modificationTime” of the folders and files as well:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can achieve it:

```
import os
import time
# Path to the file/directory
path = "/dbfs/mnt/schema_id=na"

for file_item in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_item)
    ti_c = os.path.getctime(file_path)
    ti_m = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
        
    c_ti = time.ctime(ti_c)
    m_ti = time.ctime(ti_m)
          
    print(f"The file {file_item} located at the path {path} was created at {c_ti} and was last modified at {m_ti}")
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/schema_id=na' even when the path is fine and i can see the files inside it with %fs ls '/mnt/schema_id=na' i am still getting the error

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/schema_id=na' 
thats the error

Comment: possible permission issue?

Comment: i can see the list of files and can read them as a dataframe too

Comment: are you running your script as a user or as root?

Comment: as a user i am running it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232069/discussion-between-ewong-and-batman-special).

Comment: You should add /dbfs/ at the start of your path when using os methods.

Comment: @AxelR. so something like ```path = '/dbfs/mnt/...'```?

Comment: @ewong Exactly !

Comment: @AxelR. Thanks!  I was ignorant of the underlying filesystem type.  I assumed it was a normal mount point.   Silly me.  try the updated code

Comment: @Ewong You're welcome. It comes from the fact that non-Spark based libraries are often using the local file API instead of the dbfs API. See some info here if you want : https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis